# How to stitching(side by side ) more than one video using xuggler

Tags: overlay, xuggler

I have to stitch more than one video streams,it may be recorded file or live streams

I have seen some video on the [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fI0IduBqLWA).

can i do it with Xuggler?

Any sample code ,link, advice, idea will be highly appreciated.